# Merge facebook page with ghost page

Tags: facebook

when I added the open-graph meta data to my website, every Like that my webpage gets is saved only for the webpage under a "ghost page". means that if i want to create a "facebook page" for the website, it's totally separated from the website, and i need to re-build my audience again.

is there a way to merge between them?
For example, if I insert a Like-Box to my website, and I click on the Facebook link in the Like-Box - it redirects me to the website, and not let me see the Facebook page.
if I'll change the link to the Facebook page, the likes number will be much lower.

I know i can merge under "Resources" but i wonder if it will transform my "Facebook page" to another link to my website. which i dont want.

So, how can I let people click on the link: "MySite on Facebook"  and get to my site on facebook and not to my site...

I think that the ultimate solution will we set the like button to the "facebook page", and not to the page itself. what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a Fan Page for you website and move the Likes over. There is a page migration / merge tool you can use, but it only works if the pages have similar names. You can find it in the Page Admin screen.

Comment: The question if the migration is to the fan page or from the fan page. i only have the migration page in the "Ghost Page" which is with the more likes.